# How can I get the external application data path in android?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I would like to store some cache data in the path **/sdcard/Android/data/**, but how can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply use `Context.getExternalCacheDir()`, this is the standard way android provides for external cache, when your app uninstalled, the dir removed automatically and don' t leave any trash for the user.

the dir pattern ends like `Android/data/your-package-name/cache/`

but you should check null for the return value (a `File` object), if null, it indicates that the cache dir is not avaialbe(like sd card removed or connected to your pc, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this before saving my files to my external folder.

```
String pathToExternalStorage = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
File appDirectory = new File(pathToExternalStorage + "/" + getText(R.string.app_name));

if (!appDirectory.isDirectory() || !appDirectory.exists()) //Checks if the directory exists
    appDirectory.mkdir();
```

Comment: you know that `getText(R.string.app_name)` may get different result depends on device locale, so the better is to set this value to static name, like "App_Name"

Comment: That is right. If you are translating your app_name string, that would create folder with different name. That would be a problem if user changes device locale while using the app. Using static variable instead is more solid.

Comment: You should not do this. Save all data in /Android/data/ on SdCard